# Adding buttons with a void method

Tags: java, swing, static, addition

I'm quite new to the programming circuit and I'm trying to learn Java systematically ending up at Swing for the moment. I think I get what void methods do and are used for but I can't wrap my head around this piece of example code (extracted from http://docs.oracle.com --BorderLayoutDemo):

```
public class BorderLayoutDemo {

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

    JButton button = new JButton("Button 1 (PAGE_START)");
    pane.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BorderLayoutDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    **addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());**
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   createAndShowGUI();

}
}
```

Why does this piece of code work, resulting in a window with 1 button (I expected this to result in just an empty window). Isn't frame.getContentPane() given as argument copied to addComponentsToPane() and destroyed as this void method ends (not added to frame)? Why shouldn't it return a Container object or JPanel object that then can be added to the frame (i.e. frame.add()).

(Question edited. The pivot keyword was void, not static. I see I've been taught this concept (void methods) with primitive types which confuses the matter)

Comment: Nobody understands why you don't think it would work. It's not great code, but each statement is pretty clear about what it does. addComponentsToFrame adds components to the content frame you provided in the argument. Once they've been added, the frame is packed and displayed (setVisible). Pretty straightforward.

Comment: But I do understand why Stegeman doesn't think it would work; the question is also pretty clear about what he thinks would happen, and makes it easy to explain what assumptions are wrong.  The answers he has gotten address his clear question, and you are incorrect that "Nobody understands".

Comment: I tried to condense the code a little bit to keep the question short and show the relevant statements. Mr. Tzhechev did understand me. (Ninja)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for pass-by-value stuff of java. Look at this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html) and you might understand the stuff behind what is happening in your code and why it is not working as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

The object is passed by reference and isn't copied. Java passes objects by reference rather than by value, as you may be used to in languages like C. So what you're passing with `addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());` is the actual reference to the content pane of the frame.

The static method then uses that reference to add a button to the actual content pane. Objects aren't copied for good reason. Imagine creating a class that contains huge arrays of data, for instance. It wouldn't make sense to copy this class every time you pass it to function.

There is an exception to this, in the case of 'primitive' types in Java, such as 'int' or 'double'. Those are treated the same way as you might've learned in C/C++. Keep in mind that Integer and Double are classes, however.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I tried to get this behaviour with int's. This got me quite confused.

Comment: IMHO, uou are completely wrong in saying **Objexts are passed by reference in Java**. Instead Object References are passed by value in Java, better read clearly or ask a question so that one can answer you in the right sense on this said topic. -1 from my side only for the reason, you said in Java Objects are passed by reference, which is never the case. Objects are never passed by reference, as you can do that in C. I am amazed how someone voted you up on this thingy.

Comment: I don't feel getting into that particular distinction would have helped to clear up the original question at all. Yes, you are correct that Objects aren't passed by reference in the same sense as in C and I never stated you could not do this in C. I did not get into the minutiae, because the question did not warrant it, not because I need to read more clearly.

Comment: See the answer I posted, run that example and see for yourself. In no way you can say Objects in Java are passed by reference. Though when you pass a single Object to a function, it gives you an illusion that Objects are passed by reference, instead Object References are passed by Value in Java. Since if they are passed by reference, then the original state of the objects will also change inside the main method, as happened to them inside the swap method, which never happened.

Comment: You are correct in saying that object references are passed by value. You are incorrect in saying objects will not change in the main method. The distinction between objects being passed by reference and objects being passed by value of reference is often overlooked because it is often insignificant. Example: `modify(SomeObj x) { x = new SomeObj; } // X is not modified in main` and `modify(SomeObj x) { x.stringMember = "a new string!"; } // X's stringMember IS modified`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify @tzhechev, that Objects are not passed by reference in Java instead, Object references are passed by value in Java, which is very much stated by Abu in the answer. To clarify the topic a bit more, watch this example.

```
class Employee
{
    String name;
    int age;
}

public class ValueOrReference
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.name = "Myself";
        emp1.age = 1;
        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.name = "Yourself";
        emp2.age = 2;
        System.out.println("Before swapping values are : ");
        System.out.println("Employee 1 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp1.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp1.age);
        System.out.println("Employee 2 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp2.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp2.age);
        /*
         * Now if Objects are passed by Reference
         * then if I swap the two objects in a method, 
         * then the actual objects will reciprocate
         * to the said change. Lets find out.
         */
        swapObjects(emp1, emp2); 
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Inside main after swap method.");
        System.out.println("After swapping values are : ");
        System.out.println("Employee 1 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp1.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp1.age);
        System.out.println("Employee 2 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp2.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp2.age);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }

    private static void swapObjects(Employee emp1, Employee emp2)
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Inside the swap method.");
        Employee temp = emp1;
        emp1 = emp2;
        emp2 = temp;
        System.out.println("After swapping values are : ");
        System.out.println("Employee 1 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp1.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp1.age);
        System.out.println("Employee 2 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp2.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp2.age);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT Case 1 :

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\classes>java ValueOrReference
Before swapping values are :
Employee 1 :
Name : Myself
Age : 1
Employee 2 :
Name : Yourself
Age : 2
****************************************
Inside the swap method.
After swapping values are :
Employee 1 :
Name : Yourself
Age : 2
Employee 2 :
Name : Myself
Age : 1
****************************************
****************************************
Inside main after swap method.
After swapping values are :
Employee 1 :
Name : Myself
Age : 1
Employee 2 :
Name : Yourself
Age : 2
****************************************
```

Though if I use only one Object and modify it's contents in some method, then the outcome will be surprising. Try the code that follows for that surprise :

```
class Employee
{
    String name;
    int age;
}

public class ValueOrReference
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.name = "Myself";
        emp1.age = 1;
        System.out.println("Before swapping values are : ");
        System.out.println("Employee 1 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp1.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp1.age);
        /*
         * Now if Objects are passed by Reference
         * then if I swap the two objects in a method, 
         * then the actual objects will reciprocate
         * to the said change. Lets find out.
         */
        modifyObject(emp1); 
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Inside main after modify method.");
        System.out.println("After modifying values are : ");
        System.out.println("Employee 1 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp1.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp1.age);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }

    private static void modifyObject(Employee emp1)
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Inside the modify method.");
        emp1.name = "Yourself";
        emp1.age = 2;
        System.out.println("After modifying values are : ");
        System.out.println("Employee 1 : ");
        System.out.println("Name : " + emp1.name);
        System.out.println("Age : " + emp1.age);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT Case 2 :

```
C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\classes>java ValueOrReference
Before swapping values are :
Employee 1 :
Name : Myself
Age : 1
****************************************
Inside the modify method.
After modifying values are :
Employee 1 :
Name : Yourself
Age : 2
****************************************
****************************************
Inside main after modify method.
After modifying values are :
Employee 1 :
Name : Yourself
Age : 2
****************************************
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I worked through the article posted by Abu which nicely explains this principle graphically. So if I got this correct it passes the reference by value, except in the case of a primitive type, where the object itself is copied while a new reference is created? Thanks for all the answers again and helping me in this quite basic understanding! Great community.